# Index C/C++ code using Emacs

Tags: emacs, cscope

How to index C/C++ code using Emacs?
Is it possible to use Cscope db to browsing C/C++ code in emacs?

Comment: Have a look at [xcsope.el](https://github.com/dkogan/xcscope.el)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEDET (built-in) does a good job for this.

Use http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html
for an introduction to CEDET.

Use `semantic-ia-fast-jump` to go to definition of entity at point.

Use [function-args](https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args) or
`helm-semantic`
if you'd like to jump within a file with `helm` like so:

[image: function-args]